# Error: Cannot find module 'dotenv-expand'

Tags: node.js, macos, docker, npm, dotenv

Trying to set up this docker container in MacBook M1 which is configuring dependencies for backend and front end. Backend is finely established but having this final error in building frontend.

[getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQCPe.png)

I've already checked and found dotenv-expand package there in package.json file, but I think it is not installing it for some reasons.

This is the dockerfile

```
FROM node:10.14

RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y \
  libgtk2.0-0 \
  libnotify-dev \
  libgconf-2-4 \
  libnss3 \
  libxss1 \
  libasound2 \
  xvfb

RUN mkdir /app 

WORKDIR /app

# Allows docker to cache installed dependencies between builds
COPY ./package.json /app/package.json
COPY ./yarn.lock /app/yarn.lock


RUN npm install yarn && ./node_modules/.bin/yarn install
RUN npm install --save-dev uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@1
# Adds our application code to the image
COPY . /app


#RUN yarn postinstall

RUN npm i npm-run-all -D

EXPOSE 8000
EXPOSE 9001


# kicks off the server
CMD yarn start
```

These dependencies I found in package.json

```
    "dotenv": "6.0.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "4.2.0",
    "dotenv-extended": "^2.9.0",
```

Comment: What's in the `docker-compose.yml`?  What's the actual error; what is in the PNG file that you linked to and what code produced it?  Are you getting the error while you're building the container, or while you're running it?

Comment: Directly quoting the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask), bold, caps, and all: **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question.

Comment: In the docker-compose.yml  running yarn start-cypress  command, the actual error is **Error: Cannot find module 'dotenv-expand'**, this is the error shown in the png file and yes I'm getting the error when I'm building the container    @DavidMaze